Is the Axiom of Dependent Choice necessary in this proof?
While typically, the Axiom of Choice and its peripheral arguments are not emphasized in one's first exposure to Real Analysis, I am trying to be as rigorous as possible in my learning as an axiomatic set theory enthusiast. As per the question, is the Axiom of Countable Choice sufficient in this proof? My main concern is that I specified $n_{k + 1} > n_k$ in the construction, but I think each $E_m$ being infinite should guarantee that each term exists. If the ADC is not needed here, in what cases is it necessary?

Lemma 1: A monotonically increasing (decreasing) unbounded sequence tends to $\infty$ ($-\infty$).


Proof. Let $(s_n)$ be such a sequence. Fix $M > 0$. Then there exists
an $N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $s_N > M$, as otherwise $(s_n)$ would be
bounded above by $s_N$ and below by $s_1$, hence bounded. It is clear
that the $N$-tail of $(s_n)$ is contained in $(M, \infty]$, as
required.


Theorem. If a sequence $(s_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is not bounded above (below), then it has a subsequence $(s_{n_k})$ such that $s_{n_k} \to \infty$ ($-\infty$).


Let $E_m = \{s_n : s_n > m\}$ for every $m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$. Each $E_m$ is infinite, as otherwise there exists an $M \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $\max(E_m)$ is an upper bound of $(s_n)$. The axiom of countable choice then specifies a subsequence $(s_{n_k})$ such that $s_{n_k} \in E_k$ and $n_{k + 1} > n_k$. Hence, $(s_{n_k})$ is monotonically increasing and unbounded above, and the theorem follows from the lemma.


After researching for a bit more, I realized that this proof doesn't even require any form of choice, but rather the recursion theorem. The main reason is the well-ordering principle for the natural numbers: we may recursively construct a subsequence $(s_{n_k})$ such that $n_1 = \min{n : s_n \in E_1}$ and, for each $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, $n_k = \min{n : s_n \in E_k \land n > n_{k - 1}}$. The second part of the question remains, though. When do we really need the ADC?
